# react with react-bootstrap. How they use it?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I just started to explore react and trying to understand how do I use [react-bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html) if is installed over bower I just followed the getting started part but I do not really understand how does should work.

here I have my markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="vendor/react/react.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap.js"></script> 
        <script src="vendor/react/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>


         <script>
            var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;
            console.log(Alert)
        </script>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

How do I generate bootsrap component with this package?

**Update**

I think I got it but I'm not sure if I use it right so in my markup

```
 <script>
        var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;
 </script>

 <script src="components/Alert.js"></script>
```

`Alert.js` is the compiled jsx

```
const alertInstance = (
  <Alert bsStyle='warning'>
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
  </Alert>
);

React.render(alertInstance, document.body);
```

Comment: I've been looking for more examples myself.  Found this and thought I'd share as it's given me a starting point. https://github.com/opolyo01/reactBootstrap/blob/master/index.html

Comment: I suggest not to define variables in your markup. It makes it harder to read code and extend it. You could define them in the js file itself.
const alertInstance = (
  var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert; 
  <Alert bsStyle='warning'>
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
  </Alert>
);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@dmasi mentioned it right in comments. This looks like a namespace issue and its missing from the examples mentioned on react-bootstrap website.

Here is an example of using Bootstrap's ButtonGroup via React-Bootstrap. You can adopt a similar approach for your code.

```html
<h2>React-Bootstrap Testing</h2>
<div id="myBtn"></div>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.25.1/react-bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/jsx">
    var MyReactBootstrapButton = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        var ButtonGroup = ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup,
            Button  = ReactBootstrap.Button;

        return (<div>
                    <ButtonGroup>
                        <Button>Left</Button>
                        <Button>Middle</Button>
                        <Button>Right</Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                </div>);
    }
});

React.render(<MyReactBootstrapButton />, document.getElementById("myBtn"));
</script>
```

Working Fiddle link: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15665/)